# Recover deleted Bigquery rows

Tags: google-bigquery

I accidently deleted all rows of table in Bigquery. Is it possible to recover it?
I've just searched similar problem but just found recover a deleted table in Bigquery problem.

Comment: Check out https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#from-clause (see the `SYSTEM_TIME` part)

Comment: You can't recover specific records in a table you can only recover a table. Since you said you deleted ALL rows I'm not sure I understand the question. BTW you can always recover the table to a new name and do a merged between the 2 tables in case this is what you are looking to do

Comment: thank you elliot. it works by using system_time